# Spring Remoting with Camel and HTTP

Tags: spring, rest, apache-camel, spring-remoting

REST seems to be a big work for me right now as I'm migrating an existing "Big" monolithic application into small "micro-services" and there are a lot Interface wiring inside.

Based on my research, A [camel based spring remoting](http://camel.apache.org/spring-remoting.html) is a great idea.

I tried it using ActiveMQ/JMS as the transport mechanism. Because the app required to access a lot of data stored in spring-session based web sessions, this approach has many issues for me.

So, the transport should use an HTTP based transport.

Do you recommend Spring remoting with Camel and HTTP ? Or should I stick with HttpInvoker mechanism ? Or REST itself ?